# Can't decode messages using goprotobuf

Tags: go, protocol-buffers

I have the following proto file:

```
package dogs;

enum Breed {
    terrier = 0;
    shepherd = 1;
    hound = 2;
};

message Dog {
    required int64 nbLegs = 1;
    optional int64 nbTeeth = 2 [default=24];
    optional Breed breed = 3;
    optional string name = 4;
}
```

And the following Go program written using the `goprotobuf` package.  The program

1. reads a Varint from stdin in order to get the length of the encoded message,
2. reads that number of bytes from stdin into a buffer, and
3. attempts to unmarshal the buffer into a Dog.

--START CODE--

```
package main

import "bufio"
import "encoding/binary"
import "os"
import "log"
import "fmt"
import "dogs"
import "code.google.com/p/goprotobuf/proto"

func render(dog *dogs.Dog) string {
    return fmt.Sprintf("Dog: %v %v %v %v", dog.GetName(), dog.GetBreed(), dog.GetNbLegs(), dog.GetNbTeeth())
}

func main() {
    var dog = new(dogs.Dog)
    stdin := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    sz, _ := binary.ReadVarint(stdin)
    bytes := make([]byte, sz)
    os.Stdin.Read(bytes)
    buf := proto.NewBuffer(bytes)
    err := buf.Unmarshal(dog)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Receiving %s of length %d\n", render(dog), sz)

}
```

--END CODE--

And the this encoded message (preceded by a Varint) (in hexdump form)

```
0000000: 1408 0418 0222 0446 6964 6f              .....".Fido
```

which i can successfully decode using c++ and libprotobuf as a Dog with

- name: Fido
- breed: hound
- nbLegs: 4
- nbTeeth: 24

Unmarshaling in the go program, however, always returns the error "illegal tag 0".

I suspect that I've misunderstood the decoding API but, so far, I can't see how.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try just umarshalling the bytes instead of creating a buffer like this:
You may also want to check to see if `os.Stdin.Read(bytes)` is actually reading sz.

```
func main() {
    var dog = new(dogs.Dog)
    stdin := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    sz, _ := binary.ReadVarint(stdin)
    bytes := make([]byte, sz)
    stdin.Read(bytes)
    err := buf.Unmarshal(dog, bytes)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Fprintf(os.Stderr, "Receiving %s of length %d\n", render(dog), sz)

}
```

Comment: Yeah, I should have been checking the outputs on all my reads.  As Rob Pike himself pointed out to me,  the first read is done through bufio, which drains the whole os.Stdin into a buffer, and then the second read, which is directly from os.Stdin, has no input to fetch.

Comment: Moral of the story:  ignoring return values is almost always the wrong thing to do.